# How to make 5 div tags on each new line

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I making a vue js application. I created component Popular.vue.
In this component i use "v-for" for loop films info from api.
All the info is in one div. This div have image, name, link, etc.

I did it like this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVHfO.jpg)

I need like this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9z0Pv.png)

This is my code

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="popular__text">
      Popular movies
    </h2>
    <div class="films">
      <div class="films__about" v-for="pop in returnPopular" :key="http://pop.id">
        <div class="films__preview">
          <img :src="'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200' + pop.poster_path" />
        </div>
        <div class="films__info">
          <h2>{{ pop.original_title }}</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.popular__text {
  color: #f2933a;
  margin-top: 30px;
  // margin-left: 40px;
}

.films {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1160px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.films:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.films__preview {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0;
}
.films__about {
  margin-right: 30px;
}
.films__info {
  width: 200px;
  h2 {
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.6;
    margin-top: 2px;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Hello, let me give you a hint: `flex-direction: column`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add "flex-wrap: wrap;" in your ".films" class

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.popular__text {
  color: #f2933a;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.films {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1160px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.films:first-of-type {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.films__preview {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0;
}
.films__about {
  margin-right: 30px;
}
.films__info {
  width: 200px;
}
.films__info h2 {
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
    opacity: 0.6;
    margin-top: 2px;
    text-align: center;
  }

/*****ignore this css if your code get an issue********/
.films__preview img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
.films__preview {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.films__preview img {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
    <h2 class="popular__text">
      Popular movies
    </h2>
    <div class="films">
      <div class="films__about" v-for="pop in returnPopular" :key="http://pop.id">
        <div class="films__preview">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469317835793-6d02c2392778?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1352&q=80" />
        </div>
        <div class="films__info">
          <h2>Image</h2>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="films__about" v-for="pop in returnPopular" :key="http://pop.id">
        <div class="films__preview">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469317835793-6d02c2392778?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1352&q=80" />
        </div>
        <div class="films__info">
          <h2>Image</h2>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="films__about" v-for="pop in returnPopular" :key="http://pop.id">
        <div class="films__preview">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469317835793-6d02c2392778?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1352&q=80" />
        </div>
        <div class="films__info">
          <h2>Image</h2>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="films__about" v-for="pop in returnPopular" :key="http://pop.id">
        <div class="films__preview">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469317835793-6d02c2392778?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1352&q=80" />
        </div>
        <div class="films__info">
          <h2>Image</h2>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="films__about" v-for="pop in returnPopular" :key="http://pop.id">
        <div class="films__preview">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469317835793-6d02c2392778?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1352&q=80" />
        </div>
        <div class="films__info">
          <h2>Image</h2>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="films__about" v-for="pop in returnPopular" :key="http://pop.id">
        <div class="films__preview">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469317835793-6d02c2392778?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1352&q=80" />
        </div>
        <div class="films__info">
          <h2>Image</h2>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="films__about" v-for="pop in returnPopular" :key="http://pop.id">
        <div class="films__preview">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469317835793-6d02c2392778?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1352&q=80" />
        </div>
        <div class="films__info">
          <h2>Image</h2>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="films__about" v-for="pop in returnPopular" :key="http://pop.id">
        <div class="films__preview">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469317835793-6d02c2392778?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1352&q=80" />
        </div>
        <div class="films__info">
          <h2>Image</h2>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="films__about" v-for="pop in returnPopular" :key="http://pop.id">
        <div class="films__preview">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469317835793-6d02c2392778?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1352&q=80" />
        </div>
        <div class="films__info">
          <h2>Image</h2>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="films__about" v-for="pop in returnPopular" :key="http://pop.id">
        <div class="films__preview">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469317835793-6d02c2392778?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1352&q=80" />
        </div>
        <div class="films__info">
          <h2>Image</h2>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="films__about" v-for="pop in returnPopular" :key="http://pop.id">
        <div class="films__preview">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1469317835793-6d02c2392778?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1352&q=80" />
        </div>
        <div class="films__info">
          <h2>Image</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your `films` class the **grid** and **grid-template-columns**.
See here on [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_grid-template-columns.asp).

grid-template-columns with 5-times auto will set 5 columns. You can also make fixed sizes.

```css
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
```